# How node app route and nginx location matches?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am going to run node app on nginx.

Here is nginx configuration.

```
location /first {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

And here is node app router.

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```

But when I access server via x.x.x.x/first
I get 404 errors.
What is the reason.
Please let me know if you know.